# How Do I pass a value into run() function of java runnable from main method

Tags: java, runnable

Here trying to pass `id` to `run()` function but it prints `Cannot resolve symbol id`

```
public class main2 implements Runnable {

    public main2(int id) {
        //
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("ID in the run: " + id); // Cannot resolve symbol id
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        int id = 5;
        System.out.println("ID in the main: " + id);
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[1];
        threads[0] = new Thread(new main2(id));
        threads[0].start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions: class names should be capitalized. Also use the `@Override` annotation where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can have an instance field in your `main2` class:

```
public class main2 implements Runnable {
    private int id;
    public main2(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("ID in the run: " + this.id);
    }

    ...
```

But as all this is in the same class, you can simply use a lambda expression that has access to a local variable of the `main` method, which would also eliminate the need for a `main2` instance:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    int id = 5;
    System.out.println("ID in the main: " + id);
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[1];
    threads[0] = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("ID in the run: " + id));
    threads[0].start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your "main" class has the method run(), you can have a field variable in it and have the constructor set its value. 
You're already using a constructor to get the value. You just need to make a new field variable and set its value.

```
public class main2 implements Runnable {
int id;
public main2(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("ID in the run: "+id); // Cannot resolve symbol id
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    int id = 5;
    System.out.println("ID in the main: "+id);
    Thread[] threads = new Thread [1];
    threads[0] = new Thread(new main2(id));
    threads[0].start();
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Just set it as a variable of your class. Then you have access to it:

```
private int id;    

public class main2 implements Runnable {
    public main2(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

public void run() {
    System.out.println("ID in the run: "+id); // Cannot resolve symbol id
}
```